# Why does this Prolog Fibonacci function cause a "instantiation_error"?

Tags: prolog, logic, fibonacci, declarative, clpfd

I am trying to calculate the [Fibonacci series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_series) using the following function:

```
fib(0,A,_,A).
fib(N,A,B,F) :-
    N1 is N-1, Sum is A+B, fib(N1, B, Sum, F).
fib(N, F) :- fib(N, 0, 1, F).
```

This is intended to works like this:

```
| ?- fib(20,Result).

Result = 6765 ?
```

But when I try this, it complains:

```
| ?- fib(What,6765).
uncaught exception: error(instantiation_error,(is)/2)
```

Does anyone understand why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second clause:

```
fib(N,A,B,F) :-
    N1 is N-1, Sum is A+B, fib(N1, B, Sum, F).
```

`N` is a variable to be decremented, and in your call to:

```
fib(What, 6765).
```

The variable is not yet defined, so you get the instantiation error on `N1 is N - 1`.

In swipl I do even get the error:

```
?- fib(W, 6765).
ERROR: fib/4: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Answer (score 3):

Now that you know it's an error, do you mind to know if it's actually possible to answer your query?

How do you would approach the problem? Your function it's ok, isn't it? Exactly, because it's a *function*, and *not* a *relation*, you get the error.

It's a bit complicate to solve it, but CLP can do !

See this fascinating example from CLP(FD) [documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/clp/clpfd.pl) (cited here)

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

n_factorial(0, 1).
n_factorial(N, F) :-
        N #> 0, N1 #= N - 1, F #= N * F1,
        n_factorial(N1, F1).
```

We need something like this, but for fibonacci.
See how easy it is:

```
:- [library(clpfd)].

fib(0,A,_,A).
fib(N,A,B,F) :-
    N #> 0,
    N1 #= N-1,
    Sum #= A+B,
    fib(N1, B, Sum, F).
fib(N, F) :- fib(N, 0, 1, F).
```

i.e. replace `is`/2 by `#=`/2 and we get

```
?- fib(20,Result).
Result = 6765 .

?- fib(X,6765).
X = 20 ;
^C
```

note, after the first response the program loops!
Do you a see a way to correct it? Or another question could be worth...

Answer (score 0):

A more clear and more natural predicate definition may be:

```
//The two base steps
fib1(0,0). 
fib1(1,1).
//the recursive step
fib1(N,F) :- 
        N >= 0, M is N-2, O is N-1, fib1(M,A), fib1(O,B), F is A+B.
```

It is also a definition with only one predicate: fib/2